# Testing some heavy memory consumption code

Tags: scala, caching, design-patterns, memory-leaks, integration-testing

I have some cache-class which aggregates some *heavy* objects for optimization in production. I need to test code which using cache but logic not related to cache. How can I avoid using cache? And run getting objects on-the-fly, not using cache. I thought about reflection, but it force me to suffer. Is it design problem or maybe I try to do something wrong?

```
case class SomeObject()

class FooService(private val cacheMap: collection.mutable.Map[String, SomeObject]) {

  /// some cache logic with put objects to cache

  def put(key: String, value: SomeObject): collection.mutable.Map[String, SomeObject] = cacheMap += key -> value

  def get(key: String): Option[SomeObject] = cacheMap.get(key)

  private def loadFromFile(file: String): SomeObject = ???

  def loadObject(key: String): SomeObject = {
      // ... some logic from loading 
    cacheMap.getOrElseUpdate(key, loadFromFile("some_path"))
  }
}


class Bar {

  val fooCache = new FooService(collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, SomeObject])

  def methodForTest(args: List[String]): SomeObject = {
    // do some logic ...
    val someObject = fooCache.loadObject("someKey") // here I can't create filePath for loading directly from file
    // fooCache updates, but I don't want it
    someObject
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit of inversion of control:

1) Make `FooService` a `trait` with all methods unimplemented

2) Rename your `FooService` with implemented methods to something like `FooServiceImpl`, make it `extend FooService`

At this point you should think which method will be a part of the interface `FooService` and which will be hidden inside `FooServiceImpl`. 
Most probably `FooService` doesn't need both `loadObject` amd `get`

3) Make `fooCache` a constructor argument in `Bar`:

`class Bar(fooCache: FooService)`

4) When running tests pass a more simple implementation of `FooService`:

`assert(new Bar(new DummyService)).methodForTest(Nil) == "Expected")`

Comment: this is huge refactoring now, can I resolve my problem without refactoring this code?

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a huge refactoring. And it 100% pays off. Anyway, I don't know any better solution.